# Laravel Database Seeders

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello guys I'm currently working (and learning Laravel) and I make a lots of changes to my project since there are features that wasn't planned in the beginning and this requires changes in database to. I already have make some seeders that has some test data but some datas on my project are generated by code (by uploading) so I need to save them when I want to remigrate the database.

**So my question is:**
Is there any way of saving current database datas with Laravel like creating a Database Seeder with current datas in it or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one

https://github.com/orangehill/iseed

it will  generate a new seed file based on data from the existing database table.

Comment: This is a nice package although i would prefer a solution that involves the arstisan command.